# Export Django report builder .xls report from a template

Tags: python, django, reporting

Im using Django report builder, and im trying to export one of my created reports as a xls file, this is my function in views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import View
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.utils import timezone
from ..form import UsersForm, CostItemsForm, GroupsForm, SubGroupsForm, SubGroups2Form, CostElementsForm, RequestsForm
from ..models import Groups, CostItems, Requests, CostElements, Positions, ItemChangeLogs, ElementChangeLogs
from datetime import date, datetime
from report_builder.models import Report
from report_utils.mixins import DataExportMixin, generate_filename


class DownloadFileView(DataExportMixin, View):


    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DownloadFileView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def process_report(self, report_id, user_id,
                       file_type, to_response, queryset=None):
        report = get_object_or_404(Report, pk=2)
        user = request.user
        if not queryset:
            queryset = report.get_query()

        display_fields = report.get_good_display_fields()

        objects_list, message = self.report_to_list(
            queryset,
            display_fields,
            user,
            preview=False,)
        title = re.sub(r'\W+', '', report.name)[:30]
        header = []
        widths = []
        for field in display_fields:
            header.append(field.name)
            widths.append(field.width)

        if to_response:
                return self.list_to_xlsx_response(
                    objects_list, title, header, widths)
```

So, im calling this view from a template :

```
{% extends 'cost_control_app/base_cost_control_app.html' %}
{% block contentsubbase %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<div class="center-panel">
<h3>Reports</h3>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <br>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <a href="{% url 'cost_control_app:report_download' %}" >Export</a>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock contentsubbase %}
```

And this is my urls.py that connects all :

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from .views import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^reports/download/$', views.DownloadFileView.as_view(), name = "report_download"),
)
```

thing is, is not working, when i click the a label called "Export" it takes me to the empty template but no save file dialog or nothing....any idea please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found it (for anyone who has the same issue sometime), i was missing the def get where parameters where set, this is the views.py updated, put some default values as an example :

```
class DownloadFileView(DataExportMixin, View):


    def process_report(self, report_id, user_id,
                       file_type, to_response, queryset=None):
        report = get_object_or_404(Report, pk=report_id)
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        if not queryset:
            queryset = report.get_query()

        display_fields = report.get_good_display_fields()

        objects_list, message = self.report_to_list(
            queryset,
            display_fields,
            user,
            preview=False,)
        title = re.sub(r'\W+', '', report.name)[:30]
        header = []
        widths = []
        for field in display_fields:
            header.append(field.name)
            widths.append(field.width)

        if to_response:
            return self.list_to_xlsx_response(
                objects_list, title, header, widths)


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        report_id = 2
        file_type = 'xls'
        user_id = 2
        return self.process_report(
            report_id, user_id, file_type, to_response=True)
```